# XML3D getLocalBoundingBox gives "this.renderNode.getObjectSpaceBoundingBox is not a function" Error

Tags: javascript, fiware, xml3d

This is quite hard to understand, I am working with current xml3D.js version 5.2.

I am plaing with *BoundingBox() functions to ease the positioning of assets & cameras. Contents are properly loaded, The error appears unsing an **xml3D assets file**. It there anything specific to the xml3D assets ?.

### The xml3D contents

Following is derived from https://github.com/xml3d/xml3d.js/wiki/Using-Assets-and-Models

```
<body>
<xml3d class="xml3d" view="#defaultView">
    <defs>
      <!-- camera position -->
      <transform id="t_camera" translation="0 0 40" rotation="0 1 0 0"></transform>
      <transform id="m_transform" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"></transform>
      <transform id="t_Lamp" translation="0 0 -400"></transform>
      <transform id="r_Lamp" rotation="1 0 0 -0.2"></transform>

      <!-- permanent light -->
      <lightshader id="ls_directional" script="urn:xml3d:lightshader:directional">
          <float3 name="intensity">0.6 0.6 0.6</float3>
      </lightshader>
      <transform id="t_directional" rotation="1 0 0 -0.2" />
      <!-- //permanent light -->
    </defs>

    <!-- Our viewpoint from where we see the 3D content -->
    <group id="viewGroup" transform="#t_camera">
        <view id="defaultView"></view>
    </group>

    <!-- permanent light -->
    <group transform="#t_directional">
        <light shader="#ls_directional"></light>
    </group>
    <!-- //permanent light -->

     <!-- our model include -->
    <group transform="#m_transform">
     <model id="xmlmodel" src="ciccio.xml#ciccio"></model>
    </group>
</xml3d>
</body>
<script>
  // attach event to the mesh
document.querySelector("#xmlmodel").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var model = document.getElementById("xmlmodel");
    alert("my center is " + model.getLocalBoundingBox().center().toDOMString());
});
</script>
```

So when I click on the model, it runs the specified call to getLocalBoundingBox() and throws the error :

> getLocalBoundingBox — xml3d.js:15685TypeError:
>   this.renderNode.getObjectSpaceBoundingBox is not a function. (In
>   'this.renderNode.getObjectSpaceBoundingBox(bbox)',
>   'this.renderNode.getObjectSpaceBoundingBox' is undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you were having trouble with this, it seems like a bug slipped in during one of the recent updates. I've pushed a fix to the upcoming 5.2.2 patch and uploaded a preview build for you to try: [xml3d-5.2.2-min.js](http://xml3d.org/xml3d/scripts/xml3d-5.2.2-min.js)

If you're going to be using this to position cameras though you may want to use `getWorldBoundingBox` instead, as the local bounding box doesn't take into account any transformations coming from higher up in the hierarchy (for example your `<group transform="#m_transform">`. So you'd get a bounding box for the model itself but it may not be at the same location in the scene.

Comment: I am not sure to understand how positioning works. If I set the camera's `examinePoint:` value to the `model.getWorldBoundingBox().center()`, it looks like the rotation origin is set between the camera and the model . I expected this rotation origin point to be the center of the model so that model can "rotate on itself" when draging mouse. Any advise ?

Comment: Try removing the transformation on the camera's parent `<group id="viewGroup">` element. This transform is basically moving the camera an additional 40 units on the z-axis _after_ the camera's own transformation (inc. examinePoint) is calculated. That's why the rotation center seems to be off.

You could also try using the `camera.examine(model)` function. This is a convenience function but you'll still have to remove the parent transformation.